# Multiple editor-field and editor-label in one row

Tags: css

How can i have two fields in one line i.e. rather than stack vertically i want some of my fields in one line.

e.g.

Name       ---TextBox---

Age        ---TextBox---

Start Date ---TextBox---   End Date ---TextBox

My current CSS is

```
.editor-label {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    text-align: left !important;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 25% !important;
}

.editor-field {
    margin: 1.2em 0 0 0.5em;
    float: left !important;
}

.editor-label input[type="checkbox"], .editor-field input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `float: left` property in your `.editor-label` class rather than your `.editor-field` class.

http://jsfiddle.net/h8Wnh/

Comment: Thansk but my question is how can you have two fields in one row. E.g. how can you have name and age in row  in this http://jsfiddle.net/h8Wnh/1/

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h8Wnh/2/

Removing your other formatting seemed to solve the issue.